# Обновить данные в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос:

```
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kvitan ");    
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Отсюда при выводе данных получится:

```
$row['id']=12 //ид записи    
$row['cena']=120 //стоимость товара    
$row['kolvo']=5 //количество    
$row['summa']=600 //сумма
```

Далее я в форме меняю количество на 6 штук.
Возможно ли обновить таблицу без нового селекта данных? Чтобы при отправке POST запроса с цифрой 6, и ИД строки 12, Обновить столбец summa с ИД 12, где summa=(кол-во умножить на значение столбца cena)?

Comment: данные обновляются через UPDATE,а не SELECT. Если речь идет о замене данных на самой странице без ее перезагрузки, а значит без получения данных через новый запрос, то здесь поможет JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Новые данные
$id = $_POST['id']; //ид товара
$count = $_POST['count'];//новое количество

mysql_query("UPDATE `kvitan` SET `kolvo`='$count',`summa`= `kolvo`*`cena` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!